# How to see # of requests per hour on Google Cloud Platform APIs reports

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, report

Google API metrics only shows 1 hour to 30 days metrics from today/now. It shows the total but when you narrow the graph it wont update total for that gap of time.
How do I see total amount of request for specific point in time.
Besides, it only provides requests per second, which is a constant variation form my app.

I have tried using "Traffic by API" graph on Google Cloud Platform and narrowing it to shorter time.

Expected the results at the bottom to update with a count of requests of the shorter period of time.

[Screen cap of one day of metrics adding up 34,238 requests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47YCs.png)

[Screen cap of graph narrowed from 18hs to 21hs but counts still on 34,238](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LfgRd.png)

Answer (score 0):

Looking into it, it seems you can go into the desired API and then into metrics where you will find a drop down.
In that drop down you can choose "Traffic by API" and then filter the graph for the period you are interested. Then download/export that graph and process it on Excel.
In the output file you will find request per second, that you can multiply by 60000 and then create a pivot table to add up everything.